# Need clarification on Abbott's Proof of the Algebraic Limit Theorem for Sequences

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

Here is the excerpt of his proof that I do not understand

[image]

I don't understand why he concludes that $|b_n| > |b|/2$ from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that by the triangle inequality $|b|-|b_n|\leq |b_n-b|<|b|/2$. Then rearranging for $|b_n|$ you obtain the result.

To see that the trick with the triangle inequality, note $|b|=|b_n+(b-b_n)|\leq |b_n|+|b-b_n|=|b_n|+|b_n-b|$. Therefore subtracting $|b_n|$ from both sides you obtain the result.

Comment: Thank you. I stared at that line for over an hour

Comment: If in doubt always do the analyst's trick of either adding zero or multiplying by one. Generally helps out in sticky situations.

Answer (score 1):

By reverse triangle inequality $$\left||b_n|-|b|\right|\leq |b_n-b|<\frac{|b|}{2}.$$ So $$|b|-\frac{|b|}{2}<|b_n|.$$